# Android. How can I make an ImageView draw itself as a PNG?

Tags: android, canvas, bitmap, imageview, resolution

An ImageView has been loaded with a 1514 × 564 PNG image of 67KB.

A LinearLayout, containing several views including such ImageView, needs to be drawn into a canvas.
When calling the method ImageView.draw(Canvas), the canvas size in bytes increases from 67KB to 13MB! (because "draw" draws the bitmap, not the compressed PNG)

Is there an easy way to make imageView draw itself as a PNG?

So far, I've thought of extending ImageView and overriding the draw method with something that compresses the bitmap before drawing.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there an easy way to make imageView draw itself as a PNG?

No, because there is no such concept. Moreover, you already have the PNG, so it is unclear why you are calling draw()` in the first place. If you want a PNG, use your PNG.

> So far, I've thought of extending ImageView and overriding the draw method with something that compresses the bitmap before drawing.

That would be pointless, as you would then need to re-decompress the image before drawing it. `Canvas` draws a `Bitmap`, not a PNG, and a `Bitmap` is the decompressed image.

Comment: The point is that I am drawing a LinearLayout inside the canvas, and such layout contains many views including ImageViews.

Comment: @user2358649: Then if you have several 1514 × 564 `ImageView` widgets, you will need a massive `Canvas`. If you do not want the `Canvas` to be that big, have smaller `ImageViews`. If this is a `Bitmap`-backed `Canvas`, you can compress the resulting `Bitmap` to a PNG, perhaps as part of writing out to disk, but that will not change the size of the `Canvas` itself.